# Mapping capslock to control on Mac OS X: works for some things, but not others?

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I've mapped my capslock key to control using the Modifier Keys mapping in System Preferences: Keyboard.  I've also tried mapping to "right control" instead of "left control" as per http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20060825072451882 using a plist editor.

The mapping seems to work in all cases except one: I can't use capslock with left-shift to make key mappings or apparently do anything else.  capslock (as control) with right-shift works.  I'm primarily testing by using control-tab / control-shift-tab to switch between tabs.  Using the on-screen-keyboard viewer, I can get capslock-shift-(just about anything) to work, but not capslock-leftshift-tab.

My best guess is that somehow the particular keyboard I'm working on is faulty, but I'm curious whether anyone else can reproduce this or has any ideas.

Comment: I've also assigned caps lock to control, and am not having that issue. Caps lock plus either shift works for me (on Lion).

Comment: Does it also happen when you don't remap, and press `L-Ctrl`, `L-Shift`, `Tab` and then `Capslock`?

Comment: What keyboard model do you use?

Comment: Keyboard: http://store.apple.com/us/product/MB110LL/B.

Comment: Yes, if I hold L-Ctrl, L-Shift, Tab, then try to press capslock, it doesn't work.  R-Ctrl, R-Shift, Tab, capslock does.

Comment: @keflavich I have that model on a Windows machine. I'll try to reproduce it tomorrow.

Comment: I totally forgot to try to reproduce it -- sorry about that.

Comment: I just purchased the same model keyboard and I am experiencing the same issue.  Appears to be a defect in Apple's keyboard design.  So much for them making high quality stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a rather common phenomenon, especially with cheap keyboard. You probably have a keyboard that is [not designed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)#Key_jamming_and_ghosting) to handle simultaneously pressing these three keys.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is what happened: the model I have doesn't let those three keys press simultaneously.  I've tested on an identical model.  Darn.